# how to pass parameter to php function and call in html

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this function in php; a separate file, `function dbRowInsert($table_name, $form_data)`.

I included it in my php file in which registration happens. My problem is how do I call the function on form submit and pass a parameter to the `dbRowInsert` function. This is the data of my form:

```
$form_data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'title' => $title,
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'middle_name' => $middle_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'position' => $position,
    'residence' => $residence,
    'monthly_salary' => $monthly_salary,
);
```

I tried this method:

```
<form id="signup_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php dbRowInsert(tblperson, $form_data) ?>">  
...
</form>
```

Comment: Call it when the POST data `isset()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all that in the same file where register form is after including function php file

```
<?php
//include file code start
function dbRowInsert($tblperson, $form_data){
    echo "<pre>".print_r($form_data,true)."</pre>";
}
//include file code end

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $form_data = array();
    $form_data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $form_data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $tblperson = "person";
    //do the action
    dbRowInsert($tblperson, $form_data);
}
?>
<form id="signup_form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="">  
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" />   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: It would be appropiate to add a few Explenations to your Answer

Comment: How to pass my `$form_data` to the function `dbRowInsert`?

Comment: $_POST will contain ur form data

Comment: Or if u want same as:$form_data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'title' => $title,
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'middle_name' => $middle_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'position' => $position,
    'residence' => $residence,
    'monthly_salary' => $monthly_salary,
);  then build it using $_POST

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not written like JavaScript; a POST request must be sent to a PHP page for processing (unless you're using AJAX), like so

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
....
</form>
```

In process.php, you have to extract out the fields you want to send to the function.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
doSomethingWIthUserName($username);
```

Or in you case, since you are sending the entire array:

```
dbRowInsert("tblHelpers", $_POST);
```

Here's a [detailed tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) on handling POST requests.

Comment: So, my `$form_data` should be on my `process.php`?

Comment: how do I pass the parameter `$form_data` to my php function: `dbRowInsert`?